# jQuery .ready() firing event on element that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a certain page on my website, jQuery .ready() is firing even though it shouldn't

The code:

```
    var home = ["index", "about"];
    _.each(home, function(page) {
       $("body.home." + page).ready( function() {
           //DO SOMETHING HERE
       });
    });

    <html>
    <body class='test'>
    //ALOT OF CONTENT HERE
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that //DO SOMETHING HERE is firing twice even though when initializing the .ready() events, they are initialized on non existing elements

What am I missing?

Comment: No. They're firing twice because you have two pages.

Comment: @l19, $("body.home." + page).length is equal to 0, so how come the .ready() fires?

Comment: `.ready()` fires when the `document` is ready, NOT when an individual element is ready.  You are registering two `.ready()` handlers in your `_.each()` loop so thus each one gets called when the `document` is ready.  The selector used in your `.ready()` call is ignored.  `.ready()` always applies to the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array with two elements:

```
var home = ["index", "about"];
```

And for each of the 2:

```
_.each(home, function)
```

You're running the function:

```
function(page) {
   $("body.home." + page).ready( function() {
       //DO SOMETHING HERE
   });
}
```

`$().ready()` is a listener, which you're setting once per page. So it will fire twice.

The `$().ready()` function does not require a selector, although it is recommended to use `$(document).ready()`. See http://api.jquery.com/ready for more detailed info.

Comment: But the selector returns 0 on both of them so how does .ready() fires?

Comment: The `$().ready()` function does not require a selector. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: so writing $("body.home.index").ready(handler) is incorrect ? it will fire when though the element doesnt exist on the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing an array with two elements: `var home = ["index", "about"];`

For both elements, the jQuery `ready(handler)` function is executed in your `_.each` loop. The jQuery `ready(handler)` handler function is executed after a successful page load (see jQuery documentation at https://api.jquery.com/ready/) which causes your handler function to be executed twice.

Comment: I though the .ready() will fire only if the element exists and ready

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var home = ["index", "about"];
    _.each(home, function(page) {
       if($("body.home." + page)){
         $("body.home." + page).ready( function() {
           //DO SOMETHING HERE
         });
       }
    });
```